# Prevent components from spreading apart when resizing using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, gridbaglayout

Edit: Each time I try adding the `gui` tag, it switches to `user-interface`. Someone mind explaining/fixing that?

I want the client to be resizable. I want the `JSeparator` to fill the frame's width when resizing, but I want the `JLabel`s to stay next to the fields.

It starts out like this, which the JLabels are too far apart from the fields as it is:

[image: Small]

When I resize it horizontally, this is the result:

[image: Resized]

Which is obviously way too far apart. The code that I use to set up these components are:

```
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
    
    private JTextField userfield = new JTextField(10);
    private JPasswordField passfield = new JPasswordField(10);
    private JButton login = new JButton("Login");
    private JButton create = new JButton("Create Account");
    
    public LoginPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Username: ");
        add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        add(userfield, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(passfield, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        label = new JLabel("Password: ");
        add(label, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL), gbc);
    }
}
```

(Had to cut out a few things, please tell me if I'm missing anything)
I've tried anchoring, but I'm still not 100% familiar with GridBagLayout (and the constraints) yet, so I'm not sure if I'm my attempts are in the right direction.

How would I prevent the `Username:`  and `Password:`  labels from moving away from my fields, with still being able to resize?

Also, I want to use GridBagLayout. There is still a lot of things I need to add, and I do not want to use a simple layout due to the fact that I'm going to need flexibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of `GridBagConstraints#anchor`

[image: login][image: login]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class LogInTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LogInTest();
    }

    public LogInTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new LoginPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {

        private JTextField userfield = new JTextField(10);
        private JPasswordField passfield = new JPasswordField(10);
        private JButton login = new JButton("Login");
        private JButton create = new JButton("Create Account");

        public LoginPanel() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Username: ");
            add(label, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.gridx = 3;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            add(userfield, gbc);

            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(passfield, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            label = new JLabel("Password: ");
            add(label, gbc);

            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 5;
            add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL), gbc);
        }
    }

}
```

You may also want to consider making use of compound layouts, that is, separate each area into it's own container and focus on the individual layout needs for each section and then build them all up into a single layout

Comment: I tried using `GridBagConstraints.CENTER;`, but it didn't work. Mind explaining what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `GridBagConstraints.EAST` and `GridBagConstraints.WEST` are what you're after, see example

Comment: Alright, so I need to be more specific with anchoring my components, is this correct? EDIT: Thanks! Ill keep this in mind. Ill "accept best answer" after the timer is up (7 minutes it said)

Comment: Yep.  Anchoring will let you define along which edge the component will want to position itself against within the cell